# Implementation of cumulative simpson method

Tags: integration, physics, programming, simpsons-rule

I am working on a program which uses cumulative integration methods to solve differential equations, and I want to confirm that my implementation of the Simpson method is correct, as I could not find any implementations of the Simpson method in a cumulative fashion online (except in a suspicious looking matlab file).

### Function

```
def integrate(tt_step, new_val, integral_val):
    if step == 0:
        return tt_step*new_val
    elif step == max_steps:
        return (tt_step*new_val)+integral_val
    else:
        if step % 2 == 0:
            return (2*tt_step*new_val) + integral_val
        else:
            return (4*tt_step*new_val) + integral_val
```

(Written in Python 3.)

### Description

Basically, the function takes as inputs `tt_step` which is the time step divided by 3, which I considered equivalent to $\frac{\Delta x}{3}$ (my function is being used to find the movement of a charged ion in 2-d space, so all integration is wrt time), `new_val`, which is the next function value, which I considered equivalent to $f(x_n)$, and `integral_val`, which is the integral from the previous time - that is, the integral up through $f(x_{n-1})$ where $n$ is the time.

The function first checks if `step`, or the time, is equal to zero, in which case it multiplies the time step divided by three, `tt_step`, by `new_val`; this basically returns zero. It then checks if the time is equal to the time the user wants to the program to end, `max_steps`, in which case it returns `tt_step` * `new_val` + `integral_val`. The reason these two cases are pulled out from the rest of the code is because these two cases are the only ones where `new_val` does not need to be multiplied by some coefficient ($2$ or $4$).

The rest of the code then checks if $t\mod 2 \equiv 0$ (where $t$ is time is `step`) and if so multiplies `new_val` by $2$ as well, and if not, then multiplies by $4$ as well. My reasoning for this is as follows: `step` starts at $0$. Then:

- At step $0$, $f(x_0)\rightarrow 1$
- At step $1$, $f(x_1)\rightarrow 4$
- At step $2$, $f(x_2)\rightarrow 2$
- At step $3$, $f(x_3)\rightarrow 4$
- At step $4$, $f(x_4)\rightarrow 2$
- $...$

Finally, `tt_step` is multiplied only by `new_val` in each step, not `integral_val`, because it has already been multiplied by `integral_val`.

### Calling the function

To call the function (let us say we are trying to find the x position of the particle), we create a variable `x_position_integral` which we set equal to the initial position of the particle. We then have a loop, which starts at `step = 0` and ends at `step = max_steps`. In this loop, we have a variable equal to the x velocity at that time, which updates with each loop. Thus we call the function each loop as `x_position_integral = integrate(tt_step, x_velocity, x_position_integral` and append each instance of `x_position_integral` to a list. The list is then graphed at the end of the program.

### Question

Is this an accurate implementation of a cumulative version of the Simpson method? If there are any details that are unclear about the program, please let me know. To be clear, this is not so much about the programming, this is about whether or not this is mathematically correct.

Comment: A much easier and more computationally efficient way to do this is to take the endpoints, then 2 times the intermediate points, then another 2 times the intermediate points which have (in your notation) odd indices, and then sum all of those. This is easily done in Python using slicing. An even better way to do it is to abstractly define a dot product operation (just for general purpose, not specifically this purpose), and then take the dot product with the vector [1,2,4,2,...,1].

Comment: Minor error, it should've been [1,4,2,4,...,1].

Comment: A note: I answered my own question, but please, other people: if you have some new insight, a great explanation, or an answer you've been preparing, please answer! I will still award the bounty to a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather wrong. (Sorry, me.)

As proof, consider this dandy little spreadsheet, with your formula applied to the function $x^2$ and a normal calculation of the integral. The average error over fifty steps with your function is 429.17. Eesh. (Ignore the "trap" column and the error column just to the right of it, as well as the "mod" column.)

[image]

As a general summary of what's wrong - you're summing over the course of the whole program, instead of doing that sum each step. The real code is more along the lines of:

```
def simp_integrate_correctly(t_step, new_val, integral_val):
    b_a = new_val[-1] - new_val[-2]
    return t_step/12 * (new_val[-2] + 4*(new_val[-2] + b_a/4) + 2*(new_val[-2] + 2*b_a/4) + 4*(new_val[-2] + 3*b_a/4) + new_val[-1]) + integral_val
```

And behold - again in the dandy spreadsheet, with this new formula applied to the function $x^2$, the average error is -0.000000007119216775 over *500* steps.

[image]

Much better.

Comment: Also - this only really works if you *know the function*. If you don't, and just have a bunch of data points, use the method outlined [here](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/723583.pdf) - I used only  equation $A_2$, though, because using $A_1$ would've meant I added sections twice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track, but hard to make a full assessment without seeing a bit more code. For example, where is the loop over `step`?

Here's a link to the Wikipedia section on the [composite Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson's_rule) that covers the algorithm in detail.

I would also check out the [SciPy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) of Simpson's rule. Click [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py#L334-L456) for the source code, which is well-documented.